# How to make IdentityServer4 accept multipart/form-data requests

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

After upgrading from IdentityServer 3 to 4 it doesn't accept requests with multipart/form-data (Because of that breaking change: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/4502/files).
I would like to temporarly allow it to because a lot of clients send requests with that content-type instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. How can I do that?
I tried to add middleware to translate form-data to urlencoded but that doesn't work, requests look good after middleware but it's still invalid request.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/connect")
        && context.Request.ContentType != null
        && context.Request.ContentType.Contains("multipart/form-data"))
    {
        var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();

        var formData = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var keyValuePair in form)
        {
            foreach (var value in keyValuePair.Value)
            {
                if (formData.Length > 0)
                {
                    formData.Append('&');
                }

                formData.Append($"{keyValuePair.Key}={value}");
            }
        }

        context.Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formData.ToString());
        context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        context.Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

I know what I want to do is a hacky workaround, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: Actually i don't find any method to achieve it, Have you tried to get value from multipart/form-data requests in custom model binding?